# xlsxwriter - can you save as xls file

Tags: xlsxwriter

I have a script that reads data from one excel in xlrd and then writes that data to another excel file omitting the first column using xlsx writer. Problem is I need to save the new file as an xls. Any way to do this? Also, anyway to use header and data parameter in worksheet.add_table()? Thanks!

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(outXL)
writeBook = r"S:Upload\SVRSTA00.xls"

sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

cell_range_value = 0
for value in sheet.col(32):
    cell_range_value += 1
print cell_range_value

data = []
for i in range(0, cell_range_value,1):
    stuff = [sheet.cell_value(i, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)[1:]]
    print stuff
    data.append(stuff)

#Create a workbook and add worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(writeBook)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("SVRSTA00")

worksheet.add_table(0,0,32, cell_range_value,{'data': data})

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XlsxWriter cannot create an xls file. The xls file format is completely different to the xlsx format.

For writing xls in python the best module is [xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org).

Comment: That's what I started with. Redid  it in xlwt and am getting "LookupError. unknown encoding" at workbook.add_sheet. Used this to replace workbook.add_worksheet in xlsxwriter.

Comment: That is a different question so you should ask it in a new thread. You should also mark this one as accepted.